# Yahoo (YQL) request returns no data

Tags: xml, yql

I've had a working yql xml request running with no issiues for the past 18 months. All of a sudden, no data is being pulled anymore?

Has yahoo changed anything? Or does anyone know whats wrong with my request?

```
var CNames = "FL.V"; // FRONTIER LITHIUM // HUSTON LAKE MINING
// test Link // https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22FL.V%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
var yahooCall = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
```

There should be a whole bunch of stock information avaiable, however, I'm getting no results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Using https://developer.yahoo.com I got this:

> "No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes

Maybe that's the reason you don't get data.

> Has yahoo changed anything?

Probably yes.

I tried with this sample and I get the same *error*:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
```

You can try **[here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222012-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222012-01-08%22%0D%0A%09%09)**.

You have to use other way to get such information.

Comment: So I heard if http://datatables.org is down, then community tables should also be down. This might be a temporary issue.